# Excel column is clicked in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Is there a way to know if a column has been clicked in Excel? I'm using VSTO and .NET 4. I can't find any events for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of [`Worksheet.SelectionChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.docevents_event.selectionchange.aspx).

See also: [How to get the selected range](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/528ad7d4-d7f2-4a44-bb18-f539ffa02bac/get-the-selection-range-in-excel-with-vsto).